# DeleteObject doesn't work anymore in SP 2013?

Tags: development, delete

In a web application, I had a C# function to delete files from a SharePoint library.
In SharePoint 2010, everything went fine. In SharePoint 2013, it always returns an error "File Not Found".
Can someone help me ?
Here is the code :

```
    public void deleteDocument(string strLink)
    {

        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(strServerUrl);
        Web currentWeb = ctx.Web;

        ctx.Load(currentWeb);
        ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(myLogin, myPwd, myEnvironnement);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        try
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File spfVar = currentWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(strCollection + strLink);
            ctx.Load(spfVar);

            spfVar.DeleteObject();

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception expt)
        {

        }
    }
```

If the file is located at the following address : 
"http//myServer/sites/documentCollection/Library/document.pdf"

- strServerUrl="http//myServer"
- strCollection="/sites/documentCollection"
- strLink=/Library/document.pdf"

  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably this error occurs since you are trying to load a file that is going to be deleted:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File spfVar = currentWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(strCollection + strLink);
ctx.Load(spfVar);  //<- you cant load a file that is is going to be deleted
spfVar.DeleteObject(); //delete file object
ctx.ExecuteQuery();  //submit changes to server
```

**Solution**

The solution would be to remove the line:

```
ctx.Load(spfVar);
```

Comment: If I remove the line, I get another error "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."... but if I go manually into SharePoint using the same credentials, I can access the document and delete it !... quite confusing... what did I miss ?

Comment: I realized that my error comes from the **GetFileByServerRelativeUrl()**... so my _new_ problem is _"How do I have to split my document url to obtain the correct **serverRelativeUrl** ?_ In the above example I thaught that 'strCollection + strLink' could correspond to the serverRelativeUrl... but it seems that it is not the case...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution !
The **real problem** was the ***GetFileByServerRelativeUrl*** that didn't work here. Everything was ok with SP 2010, but impossible to make it work here with SP 2013. So as a workaround, I used a CAML Query. So here is the code that runs ok for me now :

```
    public void deleteDocument(string strLibrary, string strDocname)
    {
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(strServerUrl);
        Web currentWeb = ctx.Web;

        ctx.Load(currentWeb);
        ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(myLogin, myPwd, myEnvironnement);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        try
        {
            List lstLib = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(strLibrary);
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = "<View>"
                         + "<Query>"
                         + "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>" + strDocname + "</Value></Eq></Where>"
                         + "</Query>"
                         + "</View>";

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listItemCollection = lstLib.GetItems(query);
            ctx.Load(listItemCollection);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            // Document Id 
            int intDocId = listItemCollection[0].Id;

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem liDoc = listItemCollection.GetById(intDocId);
            ctx.Load(liDoc);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            liDoc.DeleteObject();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception expt)
        {

        }
    }
```

If the file is located at the following address : 
"http//myServer/sites/documentCollection/Library/document.pdf"

- strServerUrl="http//myServer"
- strCollection="/sites/documentCollection"
- strLibrary="Library"
- strDocname="document.pdf"